# C++: Is the assignment of a value to a primitive data type (e.g. bool) an atomic operation?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

Imagine having two threads, one assigning a value to a (already initialised) bool and another thread reading/checking this bool. Thread sanitizers might detect a possible data race here if the accesses to the bool are not guarded or the bool is non-atomic.

How is this possible? Is it possible that assigning to a bool is not always atomic, e.g., because of hardware characteristics like cache hierarchies or out-of-order execution?

Comment: `bool` is not atomic, use `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: The question was not about the general difference between `bool` and `std::atomic<bool>`. It was more about this "tearing effect in the middle" of a `bool` as @SkepticalEmpiricist explained it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the C++ standard does not mandate so, it is not possible in practice to get a *tearing* effect "in the middle" of a `bool` on x86, i.e. change the value only partially while another thread is accessing it. It is, however, possible that a CPU is [maintaining more than one copy of it, as a cache for each core for example.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) Hence, one thread could be "seeing" an older value after another thread finished changing it to a new one. [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) (and specifically in your case `std::atomic<bool>`) provides you with [*memory barriers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) to remedy this issue.

Comment: Without std::atomic the optimiser may cache the read and/or remove the write (to memory) entirely.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'd love to edit if you could provide me with a linked source or such. I couldn't find any while writing the answer...

Comment: I thought typical cache coherency protocols as, e.g., MESI on intel processors would make sure that threads cannot read differing values from cache.

Comment: @Benski I believe you are correct, only that it is achieved by using [*memory barriers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol#Memory_Barriers) -- for which in C++ you have these `std::atomic`s.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist was getting around to it when this got posted: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180924-00/?p=99805  _"...The assembly code loads ptr into a register once (at the start of the loop), and then it compares the value pointed-to by that register against zero. It never reloads the ptr variable, so it never notices that the thread changed the value of ptr to point to a different value...."_

Comment: @RichardCritten This is great stuff, I'm trying to reproduce on multiple compilers, playing around with optimization flags. So far to no avail... I'd love to add an edit with a link as a proof. Did you happen to succeed getting a repro, visible in the assembly like the costumer of Raymond Chen had described?